# How to show the second fundamental form of a flat minimal surface is zero?

Tags: geometry, curvature, minimal-surfaces

The surface is flat if its Guassian curvature vanishes everywhere.
The surface is minimal if ist mean curvature vanishes everywhere.
Therefore, for a function f(x,y), its corresponding surface's Gaussian curvature and mean curvature are both 0.

My question is how to show its second fundamental form
Ldu^2 + 2Mdudv + Ndv^2 = 0?

Comment: I have no idea what the function $f(x,y)$ is doing in your question. Here's the major hint: If $H=K=0$, what does this say about the eigenvalues of the shape operator? How is the shape operator defined in terms of the first and second fundamental form? Please do not post homework problems with zero effort. And if you don't show us what you know and how you're approaching it, we may well use terms that you don't know. That's your own fault.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If you meant $r(u,v)$ then due to orthogonality between normal N and tangent vectors we have

$$ N \cdot r_1=0 $$

Differentiate w.r.t. $u$ we have by Chain Rule $ \; N\cdot r_{11} + N_1 \cdot r_{1} =0 $

and  since $ (N_1, r_1) $ are orthogonal their dot product vanishes leaving $ (r_{11}\cdot N) =L=0$. Differentiation w.r.t. $v$ leaves  $M=0$.

Similarly $ N \cdot r_2=0 $, again differentiate w.r.t $v$ in $ N\cdot r_{22} +N_2\cdot r_{2}   $ second  term vanishes  leaving the first term $ (M= r_{22}\cdot N=0 )$  so that

$$ L  du^2+ 2 M du dv + N dv^2 =0 ;\ $$

Moreover in the plane i.e., principal scalar curvatures  are all zero

$$ \{ k_1k_2=0, k_1+k_2=0\} \to \{k_1=0,k_2=0\} .$$